# how to set the locale prefix in hreflang tag in Laravel Localization

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-localization

I'm working on an international website with **3 languages (Eng - FR and AR)** based on **laravel localization**. And I want to set the locale prefix in **hreflang tag**.

**My site is structured like this:**

```
http://example.com/{locale}

<ul>
    <a href="{{ url('lang/en') }}" hreflang="LANGUAGE PREFIX">English</a>
    <a href="{{ url('lang/fr') }}" hreflang="LANGUAGE PREFIX">French</a>
    <a href="{{ url('lang/ar') }}" hreflang="LANGUAGE PREFIX">Arabic</a>
</ul>
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('lang/{locale}', [LocalizationController::class, 'lang']);
```

**LocalizationController**

```
class LocalizationController extends Controller
{
    public function lang($locale) {
        App::setlocale($locale);
        session()->put('locale', $locale);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app, you have access to the current locale via `App::getLocale()`.

So I think you could use

```
hreflang="{{ App::getLocale() }}"
```

to set the hreflang attribute of your links to the current locale.

Comment: maybe I got your question wrong - sorry >.< do you want to set the locale of the language in each link? I wonder, shouldn't the hreflang attribute always have the language in which the site is currently displayed?

Comment: if you want to set the locale for the link leading to french site as "fr", I think you could hardcode it?  (as example and do it for all languages)